# Mongodb aggregate on nested field 2 level

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

please help to fetch the aggregate results from this object. In this, I want to get average on the property which is at the 2nd level

```
{
 "cid": "c1",
 "type": "A"
 "level1":
 {
  "level2":
   {
    "score": 10
   }
 }
},
{
 "cid": "c2",
 "type": "A"
 "level1":
 {
  "level2":
   {
    "score": 20
   }
 }
},
{
 "cid": "c3",
 "type": "B"
 "level1":
 {
  "level2":
   {
    "score": 5
   }
 }
},
{
 "cid": "c4",
 "type": "B"
 "level1":
 {
  "level2":
   {
    "score": 15
   }
 }
}
```

So I need 2 results out of this:

first - Average of score: this should return: `12.5`

second - average by type

```
-------------------
A  15
B  10
```

Please help to share the way to get the result out of this.

Comment: how many different types do you've like are those fixed with everytime `A` & `B` ?

Comment: If your field names are consistent, you should be able to do this with a $group stage or two.  If the field names are dynamic, this might require some work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform `$group` twice. In the last stage, we combine `type` avg and general avg for all documents.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$type",
      avg: {
        $avg: "$level1.level2.score"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      avg: {
        $avg: "$avg"
      },
      data: {
        $push: {
          k: "$_id",
          v: "$avg"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        $mergeObjects: [
          {
            $arrayToObject: "$data"
          },
          {
            avg: "$avg"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/VyKrfIDpYwN) | [Null level2](https://mongoplayground.net/p/qK4SrJigt5o)

**Note:** If `level1` and `level2` are dynamic, let me know

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it is very helpful. however, it isn't calculating average on the null object if any. Please help to calculate as per below collection

[
  {
    "cid": "c1",
    "type": "A",
    "level1": {}
  },
  {
    "cid": "c2",
    "type": "A",
    "level1": {
      "level2": {
        "score": 20
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "cid": "c3",
    "type": "B",
    "level1": {
      "level2": {
        "score": 5
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "cid": "c4",
    "type": "B",
    "level1": {
      "level2": {
        "score": 15
      }
    }
  }
]

Comment: @user12883228 Do you need [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/qK4SrJigt5o)?